# Accessing battery usage graph on Android 8

Tags: 8.0-oreo, battery-history

How can I access the battery usage graph on Android 8? This is the graph that shows the battery drain since last the last charge and estimates the number of hours left on the current charge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to `Settings` and select `Battery`. Tap on the large battery image in the battery section and the usage graph will be shown.

[image] [image]

Answer (score 2):

If you mean this menu, you can access it from *Settings > Battery*.

[image]