# How long will battery last, assuming no usage

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, battery, battery-life, lg

**Short question:**
How do I find how long my battery will last, taking into account the current settings (Airplane mode, Battery saver, etc) I have enabled, and assuming I do not use it?

**Detailed question:**

When I open the *Battery usage* app (?), I am given 3 numbers...

1. Usage on battery
2. Estimated time remaining
3. Last 3 h of usage

I understand what **#3** means.

What does **#1** mean?

The time given by **#2** does not make sense. I currently have 2% remaining, with Airplane mode and Battery saver mode turned ON, and it tells me I have 14 minutes remaining. But it has said that for the past 30 minutes. (Note: I have only used my phone a couple times to quickly check on the battery in the past 30 minutes.)

I did some searches, and the closest questions I was able to find was [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/183573/accessing-battery-usage-graph-on-android-8) and [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/190372/what-do-the-app-usage-times-in-battery-settings-represent-exactly). But neither answers my question.

Phone is a LG Tribute HD with Android version 6.0.1

Comment: You should be careful when running your phone with such a low battery level. The easiest way to destroy a Lio battery is to let it run into a **Deep Discharge**. Usually Android and the battery itself are trying to protect the Lio cells so that this should not happen, however if you enforce using an nearly empty phone there is chance that it will happen.

Comment: Thanks @Robert. I should have stated the reason for my Q... I want to make an app which will send the longitude and latitude of the phone every 1hr. I plan on getting a small Android phone and hiding it under my bicycle seat. It will function as a cheap location tracker, in case the bike is stolen. But in order for it be useful, I would want the phone battery to last ~1 week. So I really just want to get a general idea of how long a battery will last when not being used.

Answer (score 0):

That usually refers to the impact on battery given by a single app.
If you expand you are supposed to get a list of your apps running, ordered from the most costing ones in terms of battery usage.